# Can't push branch to remote Hg repo

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I spent yesterday searching via Google and looking through SO for an answer but couldn't find anyone having the exact problem I'm having.

A while ago, I created a branch at Rev 176 in my local Mercurial repo and at Rev 196 created the named branch, "Port to VS2010." See the TortoiseHg screen cap below. I've been able to successfully push the other, "006-x86 and x64 Builds" branch to the remote repo but whenever I try to push the new branch, I get this error in the log:

```
abort: push creates new remote head 207852dab969!
hint: merge or see "hg help push" for details about pushing new heads
```

Short of merging or forcing it, how can I push this branch? It represents a tentative solution that will probably never be needed, but I wanted to keep it around just in case.

(Note: You'll notice three gaps in the Rev column. They represent immaterial changsets for the "006-x86 and x64 Builds" branch. I removed them in order to shorten the image.)

[image]

Update:
Per Lazy Badger:

```
acs_FromBuildServer_edited% hg heads -T "{node|short} {branch}\n"
% hg heads -T "{node|short} {branch}\n"
24af28a99211 006-x86 and x64 Builds
69be2af28b7c Port to VS2010
207852dab969 default
86e00db4ba95 005-No Register CardContext
9df44947cc8b 004-Hack typedef boost shared_ptr
81055bcdb3cc 003-Use boost shared_ptr
6358126f4757 002-Add Meyers Fix
1e23ed012883 001-Solution
bcc01f6fbef4 default
[command completed successfully Fri Feb 12 11:15:36 2016]
acs_FromBuildServer_edited%
```

Comment: Check (and show here) heads of your repo `hg heads -T "{node|short} {branch}\n"` (or use revset in THG) - I expect new head in existing branch (while can't see it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you only have two choices.  You can merge or you can force it.  I think in your case you want to force it.

Typically, you don't want to force a new head because other developers might not be aware of the new head.  Since this is an experiment you just want to keep for posterity then it's fine to force it.  If you find out you need it you would merge it at that time.

Comment: This is a client's legacy software near EoL, and I'm getting ready to leave. I want to make sure they have this abandoned branch backed up, but I also don't want to screw up their remote repo. "Forcing" sounds dangerous. Because it's near EoL, there would never be more one than one person working on this code, and they would be informed of the two-head situation. Is Mercurial/THG just warning me that I'll have two heads because it might confuse someone, or might it have wider, more serious repercussions?

Comment: No, it's just warning you it will create an additional head.  That's all.  In a typical workflow this is bad because you won't see the new changes on the anonymous branch without some effort.  Generally, the standard way to resolve this is to `pull`, `merge` then `push`.  Since your change is experimental it makes sense to be on a different branch.

Comment: I'm assuming they have a sensible build system that doesn't just build whatever is on `tip`.  If they don't then they will build your experimental change until a new change is pushed up.

Comment: I will be leaving the most recent changeset in the production branch as tip, so, AFAIK, that shouldn't be a problem. Regardless, there is no automated build process, so hopefully the human will know to build from the production branch. I'll tag the head of the experimental branch with something like, "Experimental - Don't build."

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have possible mix of two unrelated problems

- anonymous branching (2 heads of some branch)
- pushing new (not existing on remote) branch

New (named) branch have to be pushed with added option to default push command (`--new-branch` in CLI) or "Allow push to new branch" checkbox in THG GUI

[image: Interface]

[image: Options]

Pushing additional head in bad idea in common, better to find this new head in pre-existing branch and merge

Well, as expected, you have two heads of `default` branch

```
207852dab969 default
...
bcc01f6fbef4 default
```

and according to error message head `207852dab969` (r195) is new, not pushed yet. No, closing branch will **not** allow you to push branch. If you don't want to merge or force push, you can move diverged history (from branchpoint) to another named branch

Comment: That's already checked, but I still get the "new remote head" error message. This was an experiment. Quite often equivalent changes were manually made to both branches. One would never want to merge it. I've heard of closing a branch. Would it help (or hurt) to close this branch before pushing?